# QtLineEdit placeholder: how to have the user replace chars 1 by 1 in insert mode

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

QtLineEdit - C++/Qt Creator 4.9/ Qt 5.12 / Windows widget app

**tldr: Is there a way to prevent the placeholder text from being instantaneously wiped on user input, and instead have it being replaced character by character, in INSERT mode.**

Example:

```
[ ******** ]
[ a******* ]
[ ab****** ]
```

It's a hard one to research because I get a lot of results about completely different problems with the same keywords.

To provide some context, in case maybe someone has a good but different approach to go around the problem:

The program is a personalized public address generator for a cryptocurrency.
The user designs the desired address prefix or suffix by editing the placeholder. Since it becomes exponentially harder to generate a corresponding private key, the GUI design has to discourage replacing more placeholder characters than reasonable. But I want it to be possible to decide which character positions you want to edit.

Examples of valid user input (there's more to it but you get the idea)

```
[test****************test]
[testest*****************]
[*****************testest]
```

This would make the desired output easier to visualize

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand you, in the example that is at the beginning of your publication I understand that if I write a character it is deleted * but it is normal to write it from left to right, in your example in the lower part what is the process that the user should do?

Comment: To clarify, this would be the regex validating a correct public address

  `nano_[13][1-9a-km-z]{59}`

meaning "nano_", followed by a 1 or a 3, followed by any digit or letter except lowercase L and 0 (prevents typos)

valid example:

 `nano_3moomoo77b45d1jug8szecomeqnmwgjbue1xaxz95s5338jsp77eho16moo`

Since a crypto public address is pretty long, and that's it's very hard to generate an address with more than 8 chosen characters, I want to give the option to choose if said characters are a prefix, suffix, or both.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you may want to subclass QLineEdit and override one of its [input handling functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#reimplemented-protected-functions). In particular, you could create an overriding implementation of `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)` that adjusts the QLineEdit text. The placeholder text cannot be used persistently, as it is handled separately from the model text.

Comment: That doesn't handle copy-paste I assume? Might want to implement `QValidator.fixup` instead.

Comment: That would be a more general approach, true; You would just need to create a subclass of QValidator that implements `void QValidator::fixup(QString &input)` in such a way that it updates `input` in place. By default, `fixup()` only runs under specific conditions, so a QLineEdit subclass or may still be in order to call `fixup()` whenever the text is modified.